# Reset Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, reset

I have a Asus Zenbook with windows but installed Ubuntu on it.

Now while setting up Ubuntu, I have installed some wrong files and I am not able to fix it. So I would like to reset Ubuntu, so it is the same as when I first booted it. Is this possible by one simple command or do I need to reboot my system with the USB I created?

Comment: if you want to revert to a clean install, the best way is to reinstall.

Comment: So start computer with USB, press F9 and reinstall?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have installed some wrong files and I am not able to fix it" ? If you broke Ubuntu fastest fix is a fresh install, but it depends on how you broke it. Some things are easier to fix than others.

Comment: Adding to the above, without knowing *exactly* what you did this question is unanswerable and Revery's suggestion is the only sound advice anyone can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entering at this discussion, your basic question is:

> Is this possible by one simple command or do I need to reboot my system with the USB I created?

You must reboot your system with USB you created.There's [some simple commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434635/reinstalling-ubuntu-via-terminal) to do it, but as you "installed wrong files", we could imagine may some of them be critical files, so these line-commands may not do a good work for you.

To save time and be successful, just reboot USB and do a fresh install.