# Unable to Login after a new install

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, login, xserver

Just installed a new install along with Windows 10.

Setup root (/), swap and /home partitions; and then setup display name, computer name, username and password.

Can't login after restarting machine. Doesn't throw an error on password. It looks like it is about to start X and then gets back to the login screen. Tried restarting machine few times - no luck.

From other Q&A, it looked like a password error - but in my case no error is shown. Is the problem with starting X server?

Config - AMD Ryzen 1900 + NVidia 2070 + 32GB RAM + 1 TB SSD

Thanks.

Comment: There was no .Xauthority file when I logged on via sh. So, had to get the latest Nvidia driver and recompile `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`

works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try login from the console? At login screen press `ctrl + alt + F3` and enter your login credentials. If that does work, you can try starting the X-Session manually by typing `startx`. If you are able to start the X-Session manually, you can try to reinstall gdm(3) by deleting it `sudo apt-get purge gdm` and reinstaling it `sudo apt-get install gdm`. You can further try to reinsall the ubuntu desktop like described in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434635/reinstalling-ubuntu-via-terminal). Be aware that reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop results in installing all packages of the default installation. For minimal installation use ubuntu-desktop-minimal.

If you can't login at all, it might be a password problem as you stated.

I hope those steps can help you, at least they helped me, when I broke my login screen the first few times :D