# User login failed to start session

Tags: login, gui

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 on my desktop. Earlier I had an issue with no GUI. I got the interface now with lightdm but can't login. Everytime I type in the password, I get a failed to start session message. When I try to reinstall Ubuntu-desktop, I get a ' unable to fetch archives maybe run apt get update'. I am new to Ubuntu. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

this might be a similar problem to [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1237758/1080048). Can you try those steps? But be aware to replace the gdm with the ligthdm you are using.