# Ubuntu not working properly after recovery

Tags: dual-boot, crash, reinstall

My Ubuntu 20.04 crashed but I was able to get back reinstalling using the recovery options and with some codes in the hard terminal. But the folders are not opening, icons are not showing I can only use the terminal properly. I have a dual booting of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Do I need to delete the partition and again install Ubuntu afresh?

Comment: Can you add more information? What do you mean by "reinstalling using the recovery options"? What commands did you use exactly? Do you know why the system failed to begin with?

Comment: @Nmath My system failed when I was installing opencv for c++ and it was forced shut down as it was running out of battery. I went through the internet and while machine booting advanced options->recovery versions there I chose the second version as the first one was not working and I used the hard terminal and used the codes in this link "https://askubuntu.com/questions/434635/reinstalling-ubuntu-via-terminal".

Comment: If you've already decided that you want to reinstall, you may as well use the "Erase Disk and Install" option from USB installation media. Here's the official tutorial if you need a reference: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @Nmath Thank you but my question was that since the Ubuntu desktop is opening but having some errors like folder not opening and icons not showing, do I need to reinstall after erasing disk?

Comment: If you erase the disk that contains your operating system then you will need to reinstall